# How to change webpage look using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I would like to create JQuery script which will change a look of html page. My goal in this example is to use black background and white text with big wide font.

```
$("<style type='text/css'> body, div, p, li { background-color: black; color:white; font-family:\"Arial Black\"; font-size: 20px; font-weight:bold; font-size:28px;} </style>").appendTo("head");
```

I am developing this as a part of webextension and a sample page which I apply on this page:

https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/

*(Notice: You won't find my code there, the website above is a subject or target to change)*

**The following is optional** - only if anybody wants to test the JQuery code as an extension:

If you want to check the Mozilla site using my extension you need the manifest.json

```
{
"description": "Changes the webpage",
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Facilitate my work",
"version": "1.0",
"homepage_url": "https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/",
"icons": {
"48": "icons/border-48.png"
},
"applications": {
"gecko": {
"id": "facil070716",
"strict_min_version": "45.0"
}
},
"content_scripts": [
{
"matches": ["*://*.mozilla.org/*"],
"js": [
  "scripts/jquery-3.0.0.js",
  "scripts/change_DOM.js"]
}
]
}
```

and two scripts - jquery downloaded from here:
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js
and change_DOM.js containing the JQuery code.

Which you can add to [Addons Debuger](http://about:debugging#addons) in Firefox 45 and greater

So when I apply the Jquery code on Mozilla site I can see this:

[image: example image]

It looks like there are some big images but these areas are *li* elements (green, purple, blue and orange rectangles). E.g. the style applied on the green *li* is:

```
.promo-large-landscape.encryption {
    background: #6fbe4a;
}
```

and I would like it to be black but for some reason the my style li was not applied.

So this is the question, how do it the webpage to be completely black, but text to be white.

Also if you can give me tips how to to it to detect such situation like this: there are great rectangles which are just taking space and I would like them to remove - so how to detect them. It could be just a add, but it takes most of the space on the screen so I would like to detect it. The algorithm must be general so I can apply it on any website not just Mozilla.

**Updated:**
Current code which I am working with is this:

```
$('body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, div, p, ul, li').css({'background-color': 'black', 'color':'#f7fab0', 'font-family':'Arial Black', 'font-size': '20px', 'font-weight':'bold', 'font-size':'28px', 'padding-left':'0px', 'padding-right':'0px'});
```

Comment: you can use `addClass`, `removeClass` and `toggleClass` to change the look of site.

Comment: My second idea to detect and remove the rectangles, the rule could be like this... if there is a *li* element which does not contains text OR it contains link with no text in it, then remove this *li* element... could be solution how to get rid if this type of boxes. Yet I would need a definition for this complicated rule.

Comment: you can use `.find('element')` to find in any class and then check for its text using `.text()`, and if it returns blank, then you can set its `css` `display:none` or any other stuff you want to do. You can also replace its `html` or `text` to blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `.css` function:

```
$('body, div, p, li').css({'background-color': 'black', 'color':'white', 'font-family':'Arial Black', 'font-size': '20px', 'font-weight':'bold', 'font-size':'28px'});
```

In your code change the part `.appendTo("head")` to `.appendTo($("head"))`:

```
$("<style type='text/css'> body, div, p, li { background-color: black; color:white; font-family:\"Arial Black\"; font-size: 20px; font-weight:bold; font-size:28px;} </style>").appendTo($("head"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. It works and is simple and I found that the colored *li* elements are black now. However, the reason why I can prefer my code is because my plan is to create webextension where user can write his own css into textarea and save it. In your case, it would be much more complicated to create such code from the css input which user typed in the textarea. But it is nice to see your code it short and elegant.

Comment: Thanks. I have decided to use your code because it is definitely better. I will need to find out how to parse the string with styles and add the quotes there. But it should not be that hard.

Comment: @user1141649 where the user css is saved? database or a css file? because if you save it to a css file, it will be very easy to load.

Comment: It will be saved in profile of Firefox. I am a beginner so I will learn how to do it yet but it should be javascript variable as a result. The extensions work only with javascript so this is the only thing where it can be saved as a result. Finally I updated my post a bit to send current code.

Answer (score 0):

Use classes...

```
 $('<style type="text/css">.darkTheme { background-color: black; color:white; font-family:"Arial Black"; font-size: 20px; font-weight:bold; font-size:28px; }</style>').appendTo('head');
 $('body, div, p, li').addClass('darkTheme');
```

Comment: My code and your code is not that good as the solution from Ashkan Mobayen. His code will set the styles to all the specified elements, while our code does not. So in the final, his code saves a lot of work, it is more reliable.

Comment: But with classes you can create mixed styles .. like rounded and dark ... and if you add some css property (like hiding an element with display:none) and then reuse Mobayen's code, all your elements will show up again.

Comment: I try to create my extension as easy as possible for user. This is mostly for changing colors, font and size of text. The reason why I prefer the accepted solution is that it will do it's work on 100%.